# Correct place to put downloadable files in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download

I recently made a website for someone in which they want to have a free download of a card game that they made in the form of a .zip file.

I have the download working but was wondering if there is a "correct" place to put public downloadable files according to Rails. When I put the .zip file in my public folder and change my download_cards method to reflect the changes I get an "unable to locate file" error message.

This is my setup for the download:

Controller:

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
    def download_cards
        send_file "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/downloads/cardgame.zip", type: "application/zip", x_sendfile: true
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'

  get 'download_cards', to: "downloads#download_cards"

end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "download the cardz", download_cardz_path %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could place the file directly in the `public/` folder and then use

```
<%= link_to "Download Card Game", "/cardgame.zip" %>
```

This will create a the following link

```
<a href="/cardgame.zip">Download Card Game</a>
```

When Rails receives `GET /cardgame.zip` it will check the `public/` directory for a matching file before looking for a route that matches.  No need for a controller at all to serve static files.